# Bringing heterogeonous networks into the same internet domain

Tags: networking

I have an office server cluster (not a lot of nodes) and am expanding to use VPS instances in the cloud. Obviously the VPS instances are only approximately under my control in terms of networking.

I'd like to have all the machines addressable by x.example.com, where x is the local dns name given out by my office DNS. This way the local machines can address the VPSs and vice versa: they all get to pretend they are on the same network.

What's the usual solution here for this sort of small scale operation?

If it matters, it's all Linux and OSX - no Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Having the systems in the same DNS domain is not "on the same network" because this deals only with the easy part of having the same base domain name. In many cases, this might be all that is necessary (or even more than that!) but depending on what kind of services you run, this might not be enough and systems have to be in the same subnet/broadcast domain and you'll have to set up VPN bridges to tie it together.

The simple solution is really simple: Add the VPS systems to your DNS and it's done but beyond that, you need to know what the requirements actually are and what goal you want to reach.

Comment: Agreed - unless there is a physical connection or VPN between the system they are not "on the same network" - even with a VPN thats arguable.

Comment: I'd like the VPS to be able to address the local machines (both IP and specific service ports), which are firewalled. I am pretty sure it could be accomplished this with VLANs and other more sophistacted tools, but I'm trying to grasp a relatively simple solution here.  I don't think I need to be on the same subnet or broadcast. If the simple solutions to operate a VPN, I can probably make that happen.

Comment: Paul, I am sorry but the way you use the terminology demonstrates that you have no real clue what you are talking about and I don't think you can be helped in the context of a Q&A site like [SF]. My suggestion would be to get outside help to setup your environment in a secure and reliable way.